# Lifty and SBT 0.12

Tags: scala, sbt, lifty

I'm new to using SBT, and I'm trying to install and configure [Lifty](http://lifty.github.io/), however when I try to run sbt, I get the following error:

```
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.lifty#lifty;1.7.4: not found
```

As per the [Installing the Plugin](http://lifty.github.io/Installing+The+Plugin.html) instructions for Lifty, my `~/.sbt/plugins/build.sbt` file looks like:

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("sbt-plugin-releases", new URL("http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
addSbtPlugin("org.lifty" % "lifty" % "1.7.4")
```

And my `~/.sbt/build.sbt` file includes the line:

```
seq( Lifty.liftySettings : _*)
```

However, when trying to run this, I get the SBT error listed above, and I get a similar error if I try to use the `1.7.5-SNAPSHOT` version of Lifty instead.

I'm using SBT launcher version 0.12.0 and Scala version 2.10.1 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_17) on Ubuntu 12.10.

Thank you!

Comment: lifty looks abandoned by now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong definition. Here is what you need;

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("sbt-plugin-snapshots", new URL("http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-snapshots/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

addSbtPlugin("org.lifty" % "lifty" % "1.7.4")
```

If you want to make this available for all projects, then put in `~/.sbt/plugins/plugins.sbt`. Otherwise it goes in: `ProjectFolder/project/plugins.sbt`

**But they don't have a Scala 2.10 or SBT 0.12 release out.**. Look [HERE](http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.lifty/lifty/) for what is available.

Comment: Oh so I guess the problem is that, as you say, they don't have a Scala 2.10 or SBT 0.12 release out... thanks!