# How to configure my SBT to use a plugin with a specified plugin?

Tags: scala, plugins, version, sbt, lift

I want to use the [lifty](http://lifty.github.io/Installing+The+Plugin.html) plugin, but failed to download it in SBT.

```
C:\Users\Freewind>sbt sbt-version
[info] 0.12.3
> console
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_04).
```

I followed the document of lifty, to insert the code to my `project/plugins.sbt`:

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("sbt-plugin-releases", 
    new URL("http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

addSbtPlugin("org.lifty" % "lifty" % "1.7.4")
```

And to my `build.sbt`:

```
seq( Lifty.liftySettings : _*)
```

It reports warnings when I run `sbt`:

```
[warn]  module not found: org.lifty#lifty;1.7.4
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.lifty/lifty/scala_2.9.2/sbt_0.12/1.7.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.lifty/lifty/scala_2.9.2/sbt_0.12/1.7.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   X:\.sbt\local\org.lifty\lifty\scala_2.9.2\sbt_0.12\1.7.4\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.lifty/lifty/scala_2.9.2/sbt_0.12/1.7.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/lifty/lifty_2.9.2_0.12/1.7.4/lifty-1.7.4.pom
```

You can see it tries to find somewhere include `lifty\scala_2.9.2\sbt_0.12`

But from the resolver, I can find one valid url of:

```
http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.lifty/lifty/scala_2.9.1/sbt_0.11.2/1.7.4/
```

It only supports `scala_2.9.1` and `sbt-0.11.2`.

How to change my configuration to use this specified version of lifty?

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886216/lifty-and-sbt-0-12) question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sbt build definition file `build.sbt` change the scala version to

```
scalaVersion := 2.9.1
```

that should work.

Also FYI,

lifty is not under development any more. https://github.com/Lifty/lifty

Answer (score 1):

They dont have a versino for scala 2.10 at the moment, so you can't use it with you configuration