# using lifty (lift in action) with the latest version of scala

Tags: scala, configuration, lift, lifty

I am attempting to use `lifty` with the current version of scala.

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.lifty#lifty;1.7.4: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

I am using this configuration on windows in `~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/build.sbt`

```
libraryDependencies += 
  Defaults.sbtPluginExtra( 
    "org.lifty" % "lifty" % "1.7.4", "0.13.1", "2.10.4" )
```

How  do I use the latest version of lifty with the current version of scala, I want to work through the examples with the newer version.

I also tried [this configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886216/lifty-and-sbt-0-12), but it also didn't seem to work with the new version 
[Lifty and SBT 0.12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886216/lifty-and-sbt-0-12)

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/Lifty/lifty

Comment: I agree, lifty got abandoned by now. I actually think you can easily do what you want without it, just use something like a liftweb starting template: https://github.com/lift/lift_26_sbt

Comment: If you add your comment as an answer I will be happy to accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree, lifty got abandoned by now. I actually think you can easily do what you want without it, just use something like a liftweb starting template: github.com/lift/lift_26_sbt –  Vasya Novikov Apr 20 at 5:45